# Control Panel for Node based servers - cPanel for Node

Tags: web-apps, node.js, web-server, server, cpanel

I am looking to build a virtual machine to host node applications for development purposes.

I have WHM + cPanel for the same purpose for PHP based web applications, and I would like a similar solution for Node based apps. Something that allows me to have user based 'contained' applications.

Is there a solution for this? Or is this something that does not exist?

If not, any suggestions? I would like to be able to create several user accounts and each of the users have access to a place where they can create projects, without affecting the whole server or each others' apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone stumbles upon the same question, we are currently using `Rancher` to do container orchestration and management for non-production environments.

Depending on how we evaluate it, we might start using it also for production environments.

This is Rancher: https://rancher.com/